# GCP load balancer is redirecting to arbitrary host instead of 404

Tags: gcp-load-balancer

I have API running on cloud run instance running behind Load Balancer. I have configured some host and path rules. When I try to hit exact API URL and give different host in request , it gives me 404 as handled in code. But if I add /../ or /../../ (path escape) in front of URL it not reaching backend and its getting redirected to the host mentioned in request. So first it gives 302 and then 404. I want to send 404 if its different host irrespective of path.

Host and Path rules as below:

[image]